# How to efficiently return values of a map using only part of the key/ID (composite)?

Tags: java, hashmap

I create a composite key with two parts: mainId and secondaryId. I want to be able to use both parts when I need to insert a value. However, I would like to be able to retrieve a value in two ways: 1) using both parts to return just one value; 2) using only mainId to return a list of the values that have that mainId.

I have implemented 2) in the code below. However, it does not look efficient. Is there a better way to do this?

Thank you very much!

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map<CompositeId, String> map = new HashMap();

        map.put(new CompositeId("1", "1"), "val1");
        map.put(new CompositeId("1", "1"), "val2");
        map.put(new CompositeId("1", "2"), "val3");
        map.put(new CompositeId("2", "1"), "val4");

        // is there any way to do this more efficiently? //
        List<String> listValsWithMainIdEqualsOne = new ArrayList();
        List<CompositeId> listIdsWithMainIdEqualsOne = map.keySet().stream().filter(k -> k.getMainId().equals("1")).toList();
        listIdsWithMainIdEqualsOne.forEach(k -> listValsWithMainIdEqualsOne.add(map.get(k)));
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////

        assert map.get(new CompositeId("1", "1")).equals("val2");
        assert map.get(new CompositeId("1", "2")).equals("val3");
        assert listValsWithMainIdEqualsOne.contains("val2");
        assert listValsWithMainIdEqualsOne.contains("val3");
    }
}

class CompositeId {

    private String mainId;
    private String secondaryId;

    public CompositeId(String mainId, String secondaryId) {

        this.mainId = mainId;
        this.secondaryId = secondaryId;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {

        if (this == o) return true;

        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        CompositeId compositeId = (CompositeId) o;

        if (!this.mainId.equals(compositeId.getMainId())) return false;

        if (compositeId.getSecondaryId() != null && !this.secondaryId.equals(compositeId.getSecondaryId())) return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return (mainId + secondaryId).hashCode();
    }

    public String getMainId() {

        return mainId;
    }

    public String getSecondaryId() {

        return secondaryId;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are main id and seondary IDs ever the same, even between different keys?

Comment: Not sure I understood your question but it can happen that primary and secondary IDs take the same value. E.g. new CompositeId("1", "1") and new CompositeId("2", "2").

Comment: That answers it.

Comment: Why not just use three maps and populate accordingly with the proper mainID, secondaryID and CompositeID keys.  Then you can just do a  `map.values()` to retrieve the collection whenever you want all the values from a particular map.

Comment: How would be the keys of those 3 maps?

Comment: It's up to you.   One must use the `mainId` as a key, the other must use `secondaryId` as a key.  The third, could use your `CompositeId` class or just a special concatenation of the two, e.g.`"12_33"`

Comment: Not sure that would simplify the code. Furthermore, wouldn't I get "val1" in the map that has mainID equal to "1" as key?

Comment: You didn't say you wanted to simplify the code, you said you wanted to make it more efficient. Using multiple maps would  allow you to avoid using streams and filtering for large maps.

Comment: You are right but seems to me that @AKSingh addresses efficiency and code simplicity.

Comment: There is nothing in your code or explanation that says that both a `mainId` and `secondaryId` are both required.  That is why I have not posted an answer until I have all the facts.   With his code, how to you get just a list of those values that only had a "secondaryId".   `Secondary` could easy be taken for alternate.  But if mainId is always required, it greatly simplifies the code.  I will post an answer.  The decision is entiredly yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use nested maps to handle this. I have created a separate class `CompositeMap` and demonstrated the same.

#### Code

```
public class CompositeKeys {
    private static class CompositeMap {
        private Map<String, Map<String,String>> M = new HashMap<>();

        public String put(String primary, String secondary, String value) {
            if (!M.containsKey(primary)) {
                M.put(primary, new HashMap<>());
            }

            return M.get(primary).put(secondary, value);
        }

        public String get(String primary, String secondary) {
            if (M.containsKey(primary)) {
                return M.get(primary).get(secondary);
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }

        public List<String> get(String primary) {
            if (M.containsKey(primary)) {
                return M.get(primary).values().stream().toList();
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CompositeMap map = new CompositeMap();

        map.put("1", "1", "val1");
        map.put("1", "1", "val2");
        map.put("1", "2", "val3");
        map.put("2", "1", "val4");

        System.out.println(map.get("1", "1"));  // val2
        System.out.println(map.get("1", "2"));  // val3
        System.out.println(map.get("1"));       // [val2, val3]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Once I understood the constraints, I came up with this. (Using @AKSingh's idea of a nested map with some improvements).

- I used a `record` for the `CompositeId` and overloaded the constructor to substitute a string for a missing `secondaryId`
- I took advantage of the Map interfaces `compute*` methods as they facilitate the process.
- I also created simple `get` and `getAll` methods.  Renaming `getAll` to `get` will also work but it is presently more descriptive of what it returns.

You may also want to eliminate the `CompositeId` class and just use Strings explicitly.

I recommend you accept @AKSingh's answer and use this as possible enhancements if and where you see fit.

```
public class MapsDemo {

    record CompositeId(String mainId, String secondaryId) {
        public CompositeId(String mainId) {
            this(mainId, "");
        }
    }

    public Map<String, Map<String, String>> map = new HashMap<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MapsDemo().start();
    }

    public void start() {
        updateMap(new CompositeId("2", "3"), "val23");
        updateMap(new CompositeId("2", "4"), "val24");
        updateMap(new CompositeId("3", "5"), "val35");
        updateMap(new CompositeId("4", "6"), "val46");
        updateMap(new CompositeId("4"), "val4");
        updateMap(new CompositeId("10"), "val10");

        System.out.println(get(new CompositeId("2", "3")));
        System.out.println(get(new CompositeId("4")));
        System.out.println(getAll("2"));
        System.out.println(getAll("4"));

    }

    public void updateMap(CompositeId key, String value) {
        map.computeIfAbsent(key.mainId, v -> new HashMap<>())
                .put(key.secondaryId, value);
    }

    public List<String> getAll(String mainId) {
        return new ArrayList<>(map.get(mainId).values());
    }

    public String get(CompositeId key) {
        return map.get(key.mainId).get(key.secondaryId);
    }

}
```

prints

```
val23
val4
[val23, val24]
[val4, val46]
```